# Guess number game in javascript with two players

Tags: javascript, multiplayer

I have created my turn guess number game in javascript with three levels of difficulty. At the beginning, players choose the difficulty.
Next, it's the beginning of the game: each player try to guess the number.

Here my code:

```
var number = 0;
var playerTurn = 1


var levelChoice = prompt( "choisissez un niveau en tapant 1, 2 ou 3" );
if ( levelChoice == "1" ) {
  number = Math.round(Math.random()*10) ;
} else if ( levelChoice == "2" ) {
  number = Math.round(Math.random()*100) ;
} else if ( levelChoice == "3" ) {
  number = Math.round(Math.random()*1000) ;
} else {
  alert( "fais d'abord un des trois niveaux, impatient!" );
}


function displayTurn() {
  var NumberPlayer = prompt( "choisissez votre joueur entre 1 et 2" )
  if (playerTurn%2==0){
    alert("Joueur 1 c'est à vous");
  } else{
    alert("Joueur 2 c'est à vous");
  }
}

function incPlayerTurn() {
  playerTurn++;
}

function play() {
  displayTurn();

  incPlayerTurn();
}

for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  var guess = prompt( "Devine à quel nombre je pense entre 1 et 100" );
  if( guess < number ) { 
    alert( "Plus haut! Quel est le nombre?" + ( 8-i ) + " essais restants" );
  } else if ( guess > number ) {
    alert( "Plus bas! Quel est le nombre?" + ( 8-i ) + " essais restants" );
  } else {
   alert( " Bravo! Vous avez trouvé le nombre, c'était bien " + number );
  }
}
```

Everything works very fine except the turn.
Can someone explain how can I create this turn ?

Comment: What do you mean "Everything works fine except the turn" ? Also, it looks like you're calling a displayOutput function that is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Sorry for my english! the game works fine but I can't creat a real turn game. I would like to say "Player 1, it's your turn" "Player 2 it's your turn" for each turn. The game is finished when one player guessed the number

Comment: You probably haven't posted all your code (noone calls play, and, again, can you clarify what you mean by "the turn does not work" ?)

Comment: all my code is here, it's very basic with no button. For "the turn does not work" I'm gonna be more precise. When you launch my code, You choose the difficulty, then player 1 begins and after it's the turn of second player. But here, it doesn't work. there is only one player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function `play` which your aren't calling anywhere. Just do this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  play();
```

You'll probably also want to remove this line:

```
  var NumberPlayer = prompt( "choisissez votre joueur entre 1 et 2" )
```

Comment: oh my god, thank you very much it's works!! I wasn't very far. Thank you thank you